# Implementing auto complete for more than one field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-1.8, ruby-on-rails-2

I have an app, which implements a group feature. Each group has n members. Also, each group has a group specific profile pic to it.

I have been able to implement auto complete for the group feature keeping in mind the group name alone. I have referred to the following tutorial for the same:- http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=23188

I am using **ruby 1.8.7** and **rails 2.0.2** for project specific purpose. I have installed the auto_complete plugin in the appropriate directory. I am on **Ubuntu 10.04** OS

I would like to integrate two more things as part of the current auto complete feature for groups

1> When I type in a group name in the auto complete text field I should be able to also see an appropriate group specific profile picture which show up based on the entered text.

2> I should also be able to see the number of members that would show up corresponding to each group, based on the entered text in the auto complete text field.

I am facing the following hurdles going about the same:

Currently the code that I have implemented to get basic auto complete works based on group name looks like this:-

in **groups_controller.rb**

```
auto_complete_for :investor_group, :title
```

in **index.html.erb** of **groups**

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "groups"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

Search for a investor group: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :investor_group, :title,  {}, {:method => :get} %><%=submit_tag "Search"%>
```

in **`config/routes.rb`**

```
map.resources :investor_group, :collection => {:auto_complete_for_investor_groups_title => :get }
```

I am able to currently display an image for a particular group and retrieve the total number of members belonging to a group by making use of the following code in **index.html.erb** of groups:-

```
<%for inv_group in @investor_groups%>
<div class="inv_group_img" align="center"><%=image_tag "investor_groups/#{inv_group.title}.jpg"%></div>
  <div class="inv_group_details">
<%=inv_group.activated_members.size%><br>
<%end%>
```

The alignment of the view might be hay wire currently, but thats not my immediate focus. Thus kindly, ignore the same.

I have an idea of what I need to do and I have been able to write some code for the same in my groups_controller.rb

To get what I require, I tried the following:-

```
def calculate_members_count
    @investor_group = InvestorGroup.find(params[:id])
    @members_count = @investor_group.activated_members.size
    return "@members_count", :title
  end
```

Now this should give me the group title/name and the members_count. I am not sure how could I fetch the image also within the same method.

Also, from this If it could work correctly, I kinda have done some guess work for the changes to be reflected in the already written autocomplete functionality. I am not too sure if they would be correct... but here it goes..

I changed the following in my **index.html.erb**

```
Search for a investor group: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :investor_group, :calculate_members_count,  {}, {:method => :get} %><%=submit_tag "Search"%>
```

I changed the following in my **groups_controller.rb**
auto_complete_for :investor_group,:calculate_members_count

I am really not sure if I am correct till here, if so I really can't figure out what change I would now need to reflect in **routes.rb**

I wanted to also ask, do I need make some changes to my model by any chance. I don't think so, but just asked in case.

Also I guess if the auto complete text field supports query search for only one attribute, in this case would I have to define a customized auto complete search to suit my requirement? If yes I really have no idea on how to get a head start, and how to go about it. I may be just now that there would be also a need of a custom javascript also for this.

Kindly help me on this. Any inputs on this would be really handy..

Thanks for your patient reading and time..

---

**`Question Edited`**

---

I just wanted to mention, I am a newbie to Rails and have hardly 2.5 months of experience.

After much search, I realized in order to implement the auto complete feature for more than one field, I would have to use a customized auto complete method.

I have referred to the following tutorial to get the customized auto complete working for me:- http://cobaltedge.com/auto-complete-text-fields-in-rails-2

My customized auto complete method looks like this:-

```
 def auto_complete_for_investor_group_title
    re = Regexp.new("^#{params[:investor_group][:title]}", "i")

    #re1 = Regexp.new("^#{params[:investor_group][:title].jpg}", "i")

    find_options = { :order => "title ASC", :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:title]}%"] }

   @investor_group = InvestorGroup.find(:all, find_options).collect(&:title).select { |title| title.match re }

render :inline => "<%= content_tag(:ul, @investor_group.map { |title| content_tag(:li, h(title)) }) %>"
  end
```

My  **index.html.erb**  for the auto complete customized method to work looks like this:-

<% form_tag({:action => :search}) do %>
       Search for a investor group: <%= text_field_with_auto_complete :investor_group, :title,  :autocomplete => "off"%><%=submit_tag "Search"%>
    <%end%>

The appropriate changes made in **routes.rb** look like this:-

```
  map.auto_complete ':controller/:action', :requirements => { :action => /auto_complete_for_\S+/ }, :conditions => { :method => :get }
```

This code works well for fetching the group title when it is searched for. I want to modify this code to also fetch a group profile specific image and the total number of members belonging to a group.

The image that is uploaded is of type  `file_field`  and has the attribute named `:uploaded_data`  .

I also need to fetch the total number of members belonging to a group. Currently the image and the total number of members belonging to a group is displayed via index.html.erb separately using the following code:-

```
 <%for inv_group in @investor_groups%>
        <div class="inv_group contentTableGray">
          <div class="inv_group_img" align="center"><%=image_tag "investor_groups/#{inv_group.title}.jpg"%></div>
          <div class="inv_group_details">
            <span style="float:right;padding-right: 10px;"><%=show_edit_link_for_group(inv_group)%></span>
            <%=link_to inv_group.title, :action => :show, :id => inv_group%>        
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <%=truncate(inv_group.description,100)%>        
          </div>
          <div class="inv_group_details" style="width:14%;text-align: center;">
            <%=inv_group.activated_members.size%><br>

          ....( code continues further.. )
```

I also have figured out that the size of a group can be some how fetched in the groups_controller using some code like this:-

```
 @investor_group = InvestorGroup.find(params[:id])
    @members = @investor_group.activated_members.size
```

I am really not sure on how to modify this code to for the method auto_complete_for_investor_group_title .

activated members is taken as an association from the following investor_group.rb model

```
has_many :activated_members, :through => :investor_group_members, :source => :investor, :conditions => "activated is true"
```

Using the above information, I am unable to figure out how could I add  **total members belonging to a group and group specific profile pic**  to the already existing auto complete feature which works for title.

Can you please help me with the same.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Firstly, rails 2.0.2? Ugh. Secondly, I'd suggest you abandon the RJS approach and go with a jQuery autocomplete plugin. It'll let you control the display at a very fine level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in parts:

1. When you get the investor groups, you're getting only the titles with the call  "collect(&:title)". Remove it to get the whole object;
2. You don't need use the regex, you already get the titles that match with the LIKE in conditions;
3. Instead of render inline, try to make a partial that render all that you need inside the LI tag. Render inline and content_tag are good when all that you need is a small text, but with "bigger things", prefer partials.

Sorry any engrish.

**Update:**

The collect(&:title) says "from all investor_groups that you find, give me only their titles". So, remove it completely, using only:

```
InvestorGroup.find(:all, find_options)
```

It says "give me the investor_groups that you find", so you will have an array of investor_groups to use in the partial. With this, you can show the data that you want in the autocomplete list, like you did in the index.html, with a "for" statement, putting inside the "li" elements the images, the title and the activated members size.

Sorry any engrish.

**Re-Update**

Almost there. To the autocomplete works, the response from the autocomplete method must be a list. So, the partial would be like:

```
<ul>
  <% for inv_group in @investor_group2 %>
    <li><%=h inv_group.title %>, <%=h inv_group.activated_members.size %></li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Each item wrapped by a li tag, and all wrapped by an ul tag. If you look the previous code, this is exactly how it works:

```
content_tag(:ul, @investor_group2.map { |title| content_tag(:li, h(title)) })
```

An ul content tag, wrapping li content tags that wrap the titles.

And I did separate the title and the size in two erb, because I never tried put two information in the same, and don't now if it works.

Sorry any engrish.

Comment: Hi Otavio, I hav implemented a partial. I am not too sure how to collect the obj as a whole, can you kindly help me with the syntax of the same. I tried a collect(&:all) but it didn't do the trick for me as the currently working autocomplete functionality stopped working with dis change. I need to add group size to the content tag and I guess since the whole object is not being copied, I am unable to implement this requirement based on my current circumstances, as may be only the title has been collected into the instance of @investor_group.

Comment: Regarding not using regex, I tried it but it seem as an important part , but yes on a similar context removing/commenting the find_options statement seemed to have no side effects in stopping the auto complete from working as normally wrt title.

Comment: Hi Otavio, thanks for your continued support, I tried what you suggested, I am currently facing some issues in displaying the information from the partial. In my groups_controller.rb in the auto complete method I am calling the _index.html.erb partial using the following line of code and I am passing the @investor_group object also as:-  render :partial => 'index', :object => @investor_group2 . Now In my partial the code that initially worked only for group title was <%= content_tag(:ul,  @investor_group2.map { |title| content_tag(:li, h(title)) }) %> . I am presently trying to modify this ..

Comment: .. I modified this to something like.. :-                           <% for inv_group in @investor_group2 %>
<%=   inv_group.title, inv_group.activated_members.size %>
<%end%> . This doesn't work. I am not too familiar of the syntax to be used wrt the content_tag and how to modify the same to add the group member size, to the already existing group title. I presently only trying to get this working. Getting the image as part of the auto complete for me now is not a first priority. I am just trying to get group member size first.

Comment: ..I guess I have to modify content tag only, index.html.erb syntax doesn't seem to work wrt the partial..can you kindly help me with the syntax of the same.. my html concepts are not that strong and I have a feeling that has to be used along with rails helpers.. Thanks a lot..( Kindly ignore investor_group and investor_group2 mean the same, it is a typo )

Comment: Hi Otavio and Community, Thanks a lot for your support, its finally working. I just made a small modification for a more efficient search wrt find_options I removed the first "%" in the statement:- find_options = { :order => "title ASC", :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{params[:title]}%"] }. Its just that image for me is no longer required for now atleast(will surely get back if I need support on that ;) :) ). And yes this way regex was no longer required. A special thanks to stackoverflow.com also for always being there as a medium between the questioner and the answerer..

Comment: I was able to get the image also, I just thought of sharing the code in the _index.html.erb partial.. here goes:-                                                            
<ul>
  <%=stylesheet_link_tag "groups"%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, :cache => true %>
  <% for inv_group in @investor_group2 %>
    <%=image_tag "investor_groups/#{inv_group.title}.jpg" , :width => '40', :height => '22', :align => 'left' %><li><%=h inv_group.title%>(<%=h inv_group.activated_members.size %>)</li>
  <%end%>
</ul>

Comment: Hi Otavio, There is a slight thing, that I need to modify, I just realized. From the code above say if I enter a group name starting with I and say the results for it I get are as follows:- (Image) India(3) (next line) (Image) Independence(4) . Now if I select India(3) the selected option would populate the text field with India(3). What is desired is that only India should be populated in the text field as the search button would query for only India alone and it would also look very odd if (3) is also present beside India. I tried to fix this by using two li tags, its not the best option..

Comment: ..that one should try, is there an equivalent to onclick which I could try out.. in rails on clicking the highlighted text I can only retrieve/return the title to be populated alone in the text field. Thanks for your help...