# auto_complete_for: prevent the first item from being auto-selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, scriptaculous

The auto_complete_for dealio from script.aculo.us is great an all, but is there a way for me to selectively disable the fact that it always auto-selects the first item in the list?

The problem is that, if I want to type my own entry that is new, and novel, I don't want the first item in the list to be auto-selected. The reason is because when I TAB out of the field, it selects, and fills the text box with that first item.

I got around that, somewhat, by making the first item in the list the same as what I'm typing, but that's not perfect either, because the auto_complete list doesn't always update with every keystroke, depending on how fast I type. I've tried setting the list refresh rate to the lowest value (1 millisecond) but no go.

What I really want is an option in "auto_complete_for" that doesn't select that first item at all - the same way that Google Instant doesn't automatically select the first suggested search phrase - you have to arrow-down to select one.

Maybe I can do this via an HTML option that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you give the url of the plugin that you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, there doesn't appear to be an option for that, but I bet if you changed [line 284](https://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/blob/master/src/controls.js#L284) of controls.js to `this.index = -1;` it would do what you want.

Otherwise, it might be time to look for a different autocomplete widget.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are too far away from the available plugin, then I guess there is no point in tinkering around. Its best to write your own JS code.

You might want to consider this: https://github.com/laktek/jQuery-Smart-Auto-Complete

or this : https://github.com/reinh/jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another alternative that works great with Rails 3: 
http://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented auto complete for more than a field for Rails 2.0.2.

The plugin I used is:- https://github.com/david-kerins/auto_complete . Not sure if it supports Rails 3.

I have also encountered issues on implementing the above scenario and have posted questions( [Implementing auto complete for more than one field in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399991/implementing-auto-complete-for-more-than-one-field-in-rails)   ;  [Implementing a OnClick kind of functionality and formatting wrt Rails Partial-Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595613/implementing-a-onclick-kind-of-functionality-and-formatting-wrt-rails-partial-vie) ) on stackoverflow for the same, I have been lucky on getting things working for me based on my requirement.

Kindly refer to these questions, they might have relevance to your requirement.